# Select ranges (min, max) only for a sequence of numbers +1

Tags: oracle, gaps-and-islands

Select ranges (min, max) only for a sequence of numbers +1

There is a table:

```
col_number
1
2
3
4
9
10
12
```

It is necessary to obtain data so:

```
min   max
1     4
9     10
12    12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle version 12.1 or later, you can use `match_recognize` like so:

```
with
  my_table(col_number) as (
    select  1 from dual union all
    select  2 from dual union all
    select  3 from dual union all
    select  4 from dual union all
    select  9 from dual union all
    select 10 from dual union all
    select 12 from dual
  )
-- end of sample data (for testing only, not part of the solution)
select min_number, max_number
from   my_table
match_recognize(
  order by col_number
  measures first(col_number) as min_number, last(col_number) as max_number
  pattern  (a b*)
  define b as col_number = prev(col_number) + 1
);

MIN_NUMBER MAX_NUMBER
---------- ----------
         1          4
         9         10
        12         12
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a gaps & islands problem. You solve this by subtracting the row number from the value to get group keys:

```
select min(col), max(col)
from
(
  select
    col,
    col - row_number() over (order by col) as grp
  from mytable
) 
group by grp
order by min(col);
```

Comment: @sgeddes: Thank you for editing. An alias is not required in Oracle btw, so I only use them when they add something to the query (readability or accessability).

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't look at the database tag.  I'll remove it!

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can actually do this without window functions:

```
select min(col) as "min", max(col) as "max"
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum
      from (select t.* from t order by col) t
     ) t
group by (col - seqnum)
order by min(col)
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use `rownum` for this problem instead of a window function in Oracle, but why would you do that? The above query doesn't work; `rownum` is the arbitrary order in which the rows are read here; `order by` comes later. You'd have to sort the rows in a subquery first and only then retrieve a `rownum` for these rows (Oracle takes the liberty to violate the SQL standard and guarantee the subquery's order to make this work). I'd rather stick to the standard, as `rownum` has no benefit here in my opinion.

Comment: "You can..." but the question remains, WHY? What is wrong with "window" (really: "analytic") functions? They do exactly the same amount of work (less, really!) than your query; and as soon as there are many id's or such, and the question is to solve the same simultaneously for several id's, the analytic function approach will work exactly the same way, while the `rownum` approach will fail spectacularly. Add the fact that analytic functions are SQL Standard and I really see no attraction to *avoiding* them.

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions:

```
WITH 
nmin AS (
  SELECT col_number FROM numbers t WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT col_number FROM numbers WHERE numbers.col_number = t.col_number - 1)),
nmax AS (
  SELECT col_number FROM numbers t WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT col_number FROM numbers WHERE numbers.col_number = t.col_number + 1))
SELECT 
  nmin.col_number minnumber, 
  (SELECT MIN(nmax.col_number) FROM nmax WHERE nmax.col_number >= nmin.col_number) maxnumber
FROM nmin
ORDER BY nmin.col_number;
```

Comment: If I counted it right, this solution scans the base table four times and it performs two anti-joins and an aggregation at the end. I'd say, "window" (really: "analytic") functions are great!